# Adding video overlay to java-point-cloud-example

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-project-tango

I am new to google-project-tango. I want to create point cloud application similar to Google explorer lab. I looked into tango camera preview and added the code. I am not able to see the camera feed in upper right corner. Here is my code:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jpoint_cloud);

    mTangoCameraPreview = (TangoCameraPreview)findViewById(R.id.VideoOverLay);
    mRenderer = setupGLViewAndRenderer();
    mPointCloudManager = new TangoPointCloudManager();
    mTangoUx = setupTangoUxAndLayout();

    setupTextViewsAndButtons();
}
```

This is connect tango method:

```
private void connectTango() {
    // Connect to color camera
    mTangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,
            TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);

    // Use the default configuration plus add depth sensing
    TangoConfig config = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
    mTango.connect(config);
    mIsConnected.set(true);

    // Listen for new Tango data
    mTango.connectListener(FRAME_PAIRS, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData pose) {
            // Passing in the pose data to UX library produce exceptions.
            if (mTangoUx != null) {
                mTangoUx.updatePoseStatus(pose.statusCode);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(final TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            if (mTangoUx != null) {
                mTangoUx.updateXyzCount(xyzIj.xyzCount);
            }
            mPointCloudManager.updateXyzIj(xyzIj);

            final double currentTimeStamp = xyzIj.timestamp;
            final double pointCloudFrameDelta = (currentTimeStamp - mXyIjPreviousTimeStamp)
                    * SECS_TO_MILLISECS;
            mXyIjPreviousTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp;
            final double averageDepth = getAveragedDepth(xyzIj.xyz);

            mXyzIjTimeToNextUpdate -= pointCloudFrameDelta;

            if (mXyzIjTimeToNextUpdate < 0.0) {
                mXyzIjTimeToNextUpdate = UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS;
                final String pointCountString = Integer.toString(xyzIj.xyzCount);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mPointCountTextView.setText(pointCountString);
                        mAverageZTextView.setText(FORMAT_THREE_DECIMAL.format(averageDepth));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent event) {
            if (mTangoUx != null) {
                mTangoUx.updateTangoEvent(event);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
            // Check if the frame available is for the camera we want and
            // update its frame on the camera preview.
           if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                //Log.d("Message:","Camera");
                mTangoCameraPreview.onFrameAvailable();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Gurjeet Singh

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of this problem. Use TangoTextureCameraPreview class, instead of TangoCameraPreview